# Setting window title to html page in java

Tags: java, desktop

I open an html page using

```
desktop.browse(uri);
```

How can i set a window title to it because later in the program i wan't to kill the page using taskkill as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe \"WINDOWTITLE eq *SampleTitle*\"");
```

Please someone can with this.
Thanks

Comment: Change the `<title>` element in the browsed page.  I doubt there is any other way.  (And do you really want to assume that the user's preferred browser is Internet Explorer?)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but actually the html page will be at the client side. I just open it from my code and as for internet explorer i just gave an example. I have it covered for all kind of browsers.

Comment: Since the window title is based on the page's markup, I suspect there is nothing you can do.  Once you call Desktop.browse, the resulting application is no longer under your program's control.  I suppose you could download the page, alter it, and browse the altered version, but that can get complex.

Comment: My only aim is to close the browser where the html pages open after certain point in a loop. Is there any other way you can suggest to close the browser.

Comment: Depending on the content being displayed, you might be able to successfully display it in a non-editable JEditorPane, inside a JScrollPane inside a new JFrame or JDialog.  The drawback is that the Swing HTML renderer can only render HTML 3.2, and will ignore all JavaScript.  Another option is integrating a JavaFX window containing a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) into your application.